# arithmetic operation with columns in text file

Tags: text-processing, arithmetic

I have a data file which consists of two columns. I need to perform arithmetic operation with these columns as follows;

```
column_1=a(i)
column_2=b(i)
```

where  i is the line number

```
result_1=a(1)*100/b(1)
result_2=a(2)*100/b(2) ....
```

then I need to write all results into another text file consists of columns. I tried below codes but all values look Inf.

```
nawk -F, '{print $1*100/$2}' data > results
```

Comment: please provide a sample of input file and a sample of output file.

Comment: input= 100 150;200 250; two columns and two rows, output=67;80, two columns

Comment: Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  Why do you expect your output file to have two columns when you are producing only one result per line of input?  Are you expecting *all* the results (from all the lines of the input file) to be written to a single line of the output file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re saying `-F,` but (according to your comment)
your data are separated by spaces, not commas.  So this is what `[n]awk` sees

```
Line 1:   $1="100 150"   $2=""
Line 2:   $1="200 250"   $2=""
```

Once you use these in an arithmetic expression, `awk` converts them to

```
Line 1:   $1=100        $2=0
Line 2:   $1=200        $2=0
```

and so you get division by 0.  Just leave off the `-F,`
(or change your data to be comma-separated)
and you should get the output you want. 
Well, almost; on my system, I get `66.6667` and `80`. 
You just need to round the result to the nearest integer
(if that is, in fact, what you want).